# How to remove SVG background in the Inkscape by command?

Tags: python, svg, cmd, terminal, inkscape

Here is the situation. I use the Inkscape command to transform png file to svg file.
Like this in cmd:
`inkscape image.png --export-plain-svg=image.svg`

However, I need to remove the background of the svg file. 
The GUI process is (1) open up the file, (2) select all(Alt + A) and (3) selecet "Path" -> Trace BitMap -> click the Remove Background. Finally, save it.

[image]

Is there any command which can insert in the terminal or cmd even in python to do this process???

i might have thousands of svg files...

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with your command is embedding a png image into an SVG image.

What you want to do is to trace a png image to turn it into vector data. I don't think tracing works without GUI currently. What you want is not possible with Inkscape 0.92.4.

You need to either:

- use a different software or
- write an extension that can run potrace without parameters, or with default parameters or
- run potrace directly
- do this manually